# VPNC connect via additional SMS passcode?

Tags: vpnc

I have problems with my VPN connection to our office. I´m using Ubuntu 14.04 and had the VPN always up and running via imported pcf file and RSA token login.

Now my company has changed VPN login to a gateway login via username and password and after successful verification a SMS is sent to my mobile and I have to enter this passcode in additional window of Cisco VPN client on Windows.

When trying to connect with the new imported pcf file via the network-manager-vpnc plugin I always receive a "connection not possible" message. After the first connect I receive this SMS passcode but where to put this in? VPNC connection already failed and I am not able to use this passcode anywhere.

Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this two step authentication?
Maybe via console but unfortunately I also have no idea about that.

Comment: What program are they using? Maybe speak to your company's IT department?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed it with console version of VPNC. This version asks for additional passcode after entering username and password.
Unfortunately no support via the plugin in ubuntu :-(